# Why and where is Mohamed Bazoum sitting down in a small, round, cold room next to a portrait of (a young) John F. Kennedy? Is the event identifiable?

Tags: president, history, symbols, niger

DW News' July 31, 2023 video [Niger warns against foreign interference as pro-coup protests turn violent](https://youtu.be/wYTg0LTi9n8?t=142) after 02:22 shows what I think is file footage of Niger president [Mohamed Bazoum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamed_Bazoum), and I find the images *intriguing and puzzling!*

- the room is round or oval (and quite small, perhaps sufficient to meet and/or greet one person or a small group of individuals)
- Any check of Niger's climate explains that it's warm or hot year round, but the aid and/or security person standing to the sitting person's right is wearing a wool sweater and scarf under a suit coat.
- There is a [Nigerien flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Niger)<sup>1</sup> to the left of the seat and a portrait of what looks to be a young [John F. Kennedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy)

All of this makes me wonder where this was actually filmed - both the geographic region (was it cold?) and the unusual small, round room with a JFK portrait hanging on the wall.

**Question:** Why and where is Mohamed Bazoum sitting down in a small, round, cold room next to a portrait of (a young) John F. Kennedy? Is the event identifiable?

---

<sup>1</sup>Nigeri*en* is the demonym of Niger, (while Nigeri*an* is the demonym of Nigeria)

[image: file footage of enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is file footage taken from a [December 15th 2022 Associated Press interview](https://apnews.com/article/biden-africa-antony-blinken-gina-raimondo-e61f9758da2fac08aa11d1068478ffe1) with President Bazoum, on the sidelines of the [United States–Africa Leaders Summit 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States%E2%80%93Africa_Leaders_Summit_2022) held in Washington D.C.

Bazoum, as well as representatives from 49 African countries, attended D.C. from December 13th to 15th. The room appears to be in one of the [Oval Suites](https://washington.intercontinental.com/guest-rooms-suites/suites/1-king-1-bedroom-oval-suite-with-view/) at the Willard Intercontinental Hotel in DC - presumably where Bazoum stayed during his time in the capital. The painting is indeed of JFK, but it's [a print by the artist Louis Lupas](https://drouot.com/en/l/20649074-lupas-louis-xx-after-%E7%BA%A6%E7%BF%B0f%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD) of which many copies exist, so I don't think this helps narrow it down.

Comment: Hmm... the sorts of hotels I've always stayed at never had "oval suites", so no wonder I didn't understand what I was looking at :-)